# Elixir Ecto Issue - Can't make an association between two tables?

Tags: elixir, schema, phoenix-framework, ecto, phoenix-live-view

I am trying to make an association between table.

I currently have a **"users"** table with the following fields:

| id | email | password | first_name | last_name | role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | teacher@example.io | hash | Bob | White | teacher |
| 2 | student@example.io | hash | Joe | Brown | student |

I am trying to implement two new user types: **teachers** and **students**

As such, I want to make two different tables for both user types which will reference the main table like so:

- **teachers** table

| id | user_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 (reference to "users") | Bob | White |

- **students** table

| id | user_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 (reference to "users") | Joe | Brown |

I generated a new migration and created the "teachers" table like so:

```
create table("teachers") do
   add :user_id, references("users")
   add :first_name, :string
   add :last_name, :string
end
```

I then defined a schema for the teachers table like this:

```
schema "teachers" do
   field :first_name, :string
   field :last_name, :string

   belongs_to :user, User
```

Lastly, I added this to the user schema:

```
   has_many :teachers, Teacher
```

I have now successfully added the teachers table with my desired columns. The problem is, my registration form is only accommodating one changeset. The user schema does all the validation and adds the user into the “users” table when the registration is successful. But the “teachers” table remains empty. What would be the best practice to populate the teachers table with the registering user’s info?

Comment: what you can do is, on valid changeset for user, you populate teacher or student entry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to know is there is no one "best practice" for this.

In my experience, there are 2 different approaches:

1. Use `cast_assoc` in your `User.changeset` function.
2. In your `create_user` function, use `Ecto.Multi` to create the `:user` and then use this user ID to create the `teacher` or `student`.

Neither of these 2 is "better". Use whichever one feels better for you.

I'll explain  both approaches in more detail now:

## 1. the `cast_assoc` approach

In your `accounts.ex` context, you would have:

```elixir
def create_user(attrs) do
  %User{}
  |> User.creation_changeset(attrs)
  |> Repo.insert()
end
```

The `attrs` map would look like this:

```elixir
%{
  password: "unhashed-password"
  student: %{
    first_name: "Bob",
    last_name: "Smith"
  }
}
```

or this:

```elixir
%{
  password: "unhashed-password"
  teacher: %{
    first_name: "Bob",
    last_name: "Smith"
  }
}
```

I decided to create a changeset function just for creating a user, because maybe I sometimes want to just update a user without updating the associated teacher/student. So, in `user.ex` file, I have this:

```elixir
def creation_changeset(user, attrs) do
  User
  |> cast(attrs, @user_fields_to_cast)
  |> cast_assoc(:teacher, with: &Teacher.user_creation_changeset/2)
  |> cast_assoc(:student, with: &Student.user_creation_changeset/2)
end
```

And that's pretty much it.

The `create_user` function should return a `{:ok, %User{}}` (or `{:error, %Ecto.Changeset{}}`) tuple with the `teacher` and `student` assocs loaded on the user (either teacher or student should be `nil`).

You don't have to use dedicated "creation" changesets, but I have found it usually makes this easier.

## 2. The `Ecto.Multi` approach

If you're doing this, there's no need to use `cast_assoc` and you can leave the User/Teacher/Student schemas as they are. Instead, the context function will look something like this:

```elixir
alias Ecto.Multi

def create_user(attrs) do
  {teacher_attrs, attrs} = Map.pop(attrs, :teacher)
  {student_attrs, attrs} = Map.pop(attrs, :student)

  Multi.new()
  |> Multi.insert(:user, User.changeset(%User{}, attrs)
  |> Multi.run(:teacher, fn repo, %{user: user} ->
    if teacher_attrs do
      %Teacher{}
      |> Teacher.changeset(Map.put(teacher_attrs, :user_id, user.id))
      |> repo.insert()
    else
      {:ok, nil}
    end
  end)
  |> Multi.run(:student, fn repo, %{user: user} ->
    if student_attrs do
      %Student{}
      |> Student.changeset(Map.put(student_attrs, :user_id, user.id))
      |> repo.insert()
    else
      {:ok, nil}
    end
  end)
end
```

and this will return (in the happy path), this:

```elixir
{:ok, %{user: user, student: student, teacher: teacher}}
```

and either student or teacher will be nil.

OK I'm done.

I typed all this right in the browser without testing anything so beware typos, unmatched brackets and other small problems! It's just meant to be illustrative.